# React Native Vector Icons Causing Error After Install

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have installed `react-native-vector-icons`and from [their docs on Github](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#icon-component) with `npm install <pkg_name>`

and made the changes to my `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

//start my changes
project.ext.vectoricons = [
     iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ]
]
```

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
   // end my changes

and in `App.js` I have done this view below:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
   render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.navbar}>
                  <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')}
                         style={{width: 98, height: 22}}/>
                  <View style={styles.rightNav}>
                      <Icon name='search' size={25}/>
                  </View>
              </View>
          </View>
      );
  }
 }
```

but when I try running `react-native run-android`, the app crashes. This happened only after I installed this package. Here's the crash report below:

```
D:\ReactNativeDev\YouTubeUI\youtubeui>react-native run-android
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'asap/raw'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactNativeDev\YouTubeUI\youtubeui\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:3:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Module._compile (D:\ReactNativeDev\YouTubeUI\youtubeui\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\ReactNativeDev\YouTubeUI\youtubeui\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to define library name when you import that inside your component :

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'; or 
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
```

and then use it like this :

```html
 <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.navbar}>
                  <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')}
                         style={{width: 98, height: 22}}/>
                  <View style={styles.rightNav}>
                      <Icon name='search' size={25}/>
                  </View>
              </View>
          </View>
```

you can check all available icons based on their libraries in here : 
https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have done exactly that but it still throws that cjs loader-asap error. Even when I downgraded the library to match that of the video I was watching from.

Comment: have you imported the library inside MainAppication.java and setting.gradle ?

Comment: Yes, that's when it crashes

Comment: @DarthPlagueris hello mate I am getting this silly error. Which version did you downgrade the package . remember?